# Current DAC/current wave-form generator

Tags: stm32, current-source, dac, signal-generator

I am designing a PCB on which I need to generate an arbitrary current waveform.
The maximum current output is (-+6 uA), resolution >=8 bit, fast settling <=0.1 us, sampling rate >=5 MHz.
I couldn't find a commercial IC with these specs; if you know one, please suggest it.
Otherwise, I may use a voltage DAC with a V2I converting stage. However, I could not find two commercial parts that could satisfy the specs together.
Please suggest any IC that can fulfill my specifications. Also, other solutions are very welcome.
Note: I am using an STM32L476 MSU in he same PCB, However its V-DAC settels in us range.

Comment: voltage DAC and op-amps that can be used to realize your idea are ubiquitous. So what do you mean with that you couldn't find such parts? Do you want a part recommendation? That would be off-topic... So please better describe what you want to ask.

Comment: I didn't know that asking for help finding a part that I found very hard to find is off-topic! 
Sorry for the unclarity, but if it is easy -for you- to find a current DAC that meets the required specifications, please recommend it. I have been searching for almost five days with no results.

Comment: TLC7524 should be ok ...

Comment: @BakrHesham Again: part recommendations are off-topic in EESE. They present a closure reason for questions. I didn't say current DAC in my comment either, but "voltage DAC and op-amps" for your suggested V-to-I conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MCU (STM32L476) is able to do that by its onboard DAC and external opamp. Your DAC is able to run up to 10Msps

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4566-extending-the-dac-performance-of-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf )

You have to disable internal DAC buffer (too slow for your specs) and add external opamp, which you can connect as current source. Comparison of slew rate (and settling time) of internal and external buffer (there LMH6612) you can see for example there:

http://mcu.cz/images/newspost_images/40/88/step2.png
http://mcu.cz/images/newspost_images/40/88/step5.png

looks that can meet your specs.